# How to set discount price in opencart depending on quantity?

Tags: php, opencart

I would like to set product discount in opencart depending on quantity, for instance if quantity > 20 product price to be 0.8. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the "discount" tab on the individual product admin page.

So,

- Quantity: 21
- Price:  0.8
- Dates start/end: as appropriate
- Priority: If you have different discounts, set the discounts with the highest quantiles as the highest priority